# javascript array.includes doesn't work right in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, include

First of all, I'm a newbie at frontend, so my knowledge about javascript + react is based on tutorials.

I have an object that is set to the component properties. This object has an array as a property.

So inside the component, either in a function or the render method, if a write a `console.log(object.property)`

It prints the array, no error.

But if I try to use the .includes method

console.log(object.property.includes("string"))

it throws the following error:

> react-dom.development.js?cada:12404 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'includes' of undefined

so how does the array turn into undefined just for using this method?

The workaround I found, is something like this:

```
   render() {
    let self = this;
    let user;
    return(
      {
        this.props.otherarray.map(function(var) {
            self.user = self.props.object.property.includes("string") 
        })
        console.log(this.user)
      }
    );
   }
```

and then it works.

What am I missing? Is it something about javascript context or react stuff?

Comment: How were you using it before the workaround, ie include that particular code in your question

Comment: That code really doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to do? `map()` needs a `return` or get array of all `undefined` values and you usually use the `var` to do something in the map callback

Comment: `includes` returns true or false

Comment: Is this `object` prop coming from an async operation?

Comment: It seems that `self.props.object.property` is not an array

Comment: why Can’t you change this.props.otherarray.map(function(var){ to this.props.otherarray.map(var => { and assigning this to self is really clumsy

Comment: @charlietfl map() was already written. It does something else and it has its return. I'm trying to show that if a write the same code in another scope, as inside map(), the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` output is misleading you. I guess `object` is coming from an async job and you are seeing the array in the first render as `undefined` and it the second render as it is. Being `undefined` is not a problem but if you try to use a method on a nonexistent property like `map`, `includes` is a problem and you get the error quoted in your question. So, you need to check the existence of this property. I don't know your component setup but here is an example:

```js
const object = {
  property: [ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]
}

const fakeRequest = () => new Promise( resolve =>
  setTimeout(() => resolve(object),1000)
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    object: {},
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest().then(this.setState({object}))
  }
  render() {
    const { object } = this.state;
    object.property && console.log(object.property.includes("foo"))
    return <div>Foo</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work, let me understand something. I have a mapDispatchToProps method, where are defined the requests to dispatch. Then all of this methods are executed on the componentWillMount method. Then I have a reducer that put the response in a state object, and I map this object to my props on my mapStateToProps method. I assume this whole process is done in background? (I just followed how it was done in the legacy code).

Comment: and why does "object.property && console.log(object.property.includes("foo"))" wait for property to not be undefined? What can I read to understand this way of using operators?

Comment: You are welcome. You are using Redux and what you explain here is the regular process. But, the delay itself is about an asynchronous operation probably, you are getting the data somewhere else which is remote.  We use here `&&` so we guarantee if there is `object.property` then log it. You will use this logic in your components frequently: conditional rendering. Not just logging but for rendering the data itself.

Comment: So, just read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators and do some search about **conditional rendering in React**. It will help you to understand the logic. Also, do not use `componentWillMount` since it will be deprecated in the future releases. You can use `componentDidMount` instead.